# Calling JSON object with number name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

Ex:

```
{
  "123": [
     ...stuff
  ]
}
```

How do I call "123" in a jquery without returning an error?

I've tried:

`$.getJSON('insert-url-here').then(function (data) {
  console.log(data.123.length)
}`

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use square bracket notation:

```js
const data = {
  "123": [1, 2, 3]
}

console.log(data[123].length);
```

Or since it's technically a string:

```js
const data = {
  "123": [1, 2, 3]
}

console.log(data["123"].length);
```